# Prestashop checkbox check

Tags: php, prestashop

I want to know how a checkbox in module page can be made checked
My code is :-

```
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
exit;
}
class ExportOrders extends Module
{

    protected $config_form = false;
    protected $_html = '';
    protected $_postErrors = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
    $this->name = 'exportorders';
    $this->tab = 'export';
    $this->version = '1.0.1';
    $this->author = 'Decathlon Sports India Limited';
    $this->need_instance = 1;

    /**
    * Set $this->bootstrap to true if your module is compliant with bootstrap (PrestaShop 1.6)
    */
    $this->bootstrap = true;

    parent::__construct();

    $this->displayName = $this->l('ExportOrders');
    $this->description = $this->l('generating xml for exportorder based on manual and automation process');

    $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall the module');
}

/**
* Don't forget to create update methods if needed:
* http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Enabling+the+Auto-Update
*/
public function install()
{
    if (!parent::install() OR ! $this->alterTable('add') OR ! $this->registerHook('actionAdminControllerSetMedia') OR ! $this->registerHook('actionProductUpdate') OR ! $this->registerHook('displayAdminProductsExtra'))
    return false;
    return true;
}

public function uninstall()
{
    if (!parent::uninstall() OR ! $this->alterTable('remove'))
    return false;
    return true;
}

public function alterTable($method)
{
    switch ($method) {
    case 'add':
    $sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'order_history ADD `export_orders` int NOT NULL';
    break;

    case 'remove':
    $sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'order_history DROP COLUMN `export_orders`';
    break;
}

if (!Db::getInstance()->Execute($sql))
return false;
return true;
}

/**
* Load the configuration form
*/
public function prepareNewTab()
{

    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
    'custom_field' => '',
    'languages' => $this->context->controller->_languages,
    'default_language' => (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT')
    ));

}
/**
* Validating the settings form
*/
protected function _postValidation()
{

    if (Tools::isSubmit('submitexportordersModule'))
    {
    // if (!Tools::getValue('Order Id'))
    //     $this->_postErrors[] = $this->l('Order Id is mandatory.');    
    if (!Tools::getValue('EXPORTORDERS_LOCATION'))                
    $this->_postErrors[] = $this->l('Export Location is required.');


}
}

public function getContent()
{
    /**
    * If values have been submitted in the form, process.
    */
    if (((bool)Tools::isSubmit('submitexportordersModule')) == true){ 

    $this->_postValidation();
    if (!count($this->_postErrors))
    $this->postProcess();
    else
    foreach ($this->_postErrors as $err)
    $this->_html .= $this->displayError($err);
}
else
$this->_html .= '<br />';

$this->_html .= $this->renderForm();

return $this->_html;

$this->context->smarty->assign('module_dir', $this->_path);

$output = $this->context->smarty->fetch($this->local_path.'views/templates/admin/configure.tpl');
return $output.$this->renderForm();
}

/**
* Create the form that will be displayed in the configuration of your module.
*/
protected function renderForm()
{
    $helper = new HelperForm();            

    $helper->show_toolbar = false;
    $helper->table = $this->table;
    $helper->module = $this;
    $helper->default_form_language = $this->context->language->id;
    $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = Configuration::get('PS_BO_ALLOW_EMPLOYEE_FORM_LANG', 0);

    $helper->identifier = $this->identifier;
    $helper->submit_action = 'submitexportordersModule';
    $helper->currentIndex = $this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminModules', false)
    .'&configure='.$this->name.'&tab_module='.$this->tab.'&module_name='.$this->name;
    $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');

    $helper->tpl_vars = array(
    'fields_value' => $this->getConfigFormValues(), /* Add values for your inputs */
    'languages' => $this->context->controller->getLanguages(),
    'id_language' => $this->context->language->id,
    );

    $helper->fields_value[OrderID] = true;
    return $helper->generateForm(array($this->getConfigForm()));
}

/**
* Create the structure of your form.
*/
protected function getConfigForm()
{
    return array(
    'form' => array(
    'legend' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('Settings'),
    'icon' => 'icon-cogs',
    ),
    'input' => array(

    array(
    'type' => 'checkbox',
    'label' => $this->l('Select Required Options'),                        
    // 'required' => true,
    'values' => array(
    'query' => array(
    array(
    'id' => 'AllFields',
    'name' => $this->l('All Fields'),                                
    'val' => 'All', 
    'class' => 'check_all',
    ),
    array(
    'id' => 'OrderID',  
    'name' => $this->l('Order Id'),                                
    'val' => 1,
    'required' => true,                                    
    'class' => 'order_id',
    ), array(
    'id' => 'InvoiceNo',
    'name' => $this->l('Invoice No'),
    'val' => 1,
    ), array(
    'id' => 'ShippedDate',
    'name' => $this->l('Shipped Date'),
    'val' => 1,
    ), array(
    'id' => 'PaymentMethod',
    'name' => $this->l('Payment Method'),
    'val' => 1,
    ), array(
    'id' => 'TransportCost',
    'name' => $this->l('Transport Cost'),
    'val' => 1,
    ), array(
    'id' => 'OrderStatus',
    'name' => $this->l('Order Status'),
    'val' => 1,
    ), array(
    'id' => 'MyDecathlonId',
    'name' => $this->l('Decathlon Id'),
    'val' => 1,
    ), array(
    'id' => 'FirstName',
    'name' => $this->l('First Name'),
    'val' => 1,
    ), array(
    'id' => 'LastName',
    'name' => $this->l('Last Name'),
    'val' => 1,
    ), array(
    'id' => 'Address1',
    'name' => $this->l('Address1'),
    'val' => 1,
    ), array(
    'id' => 'Address2',
    'name' => $this->l('Address2'),
    'val' => 1,                                   
    'id' => 'State',
    'name' => $this->l(' State'),
    'val' =>1,
    ), array(
    'id' => 'ZipCode',
    'name' => $this->l(' ZipCode'),
    'val' =>1,
    ), array(
    'id' => 'Phone',
    'name' => $this->l('Phone'),
    'val' => 1,
    ), array(
    'id' => 'Email',
    'name' => $this->l('Email'),
    'val' => 1,
    ), array(
    'id' => 'Item',
    'name' => $this->l('Item'),
    'val' => 1,
    ), array(
    'id' => 'QuantityOrdered',
    'name' => $this->l('Quantity Ordered'),
    'val' => 1,
    ), array(
    'id' => 'QuantityReturned',
    'name' => $this->l('Quantity Returned'),
    'val' => 1,
    ), array(
    'id' => 'GrossAmount',
    'name' => $this->l('Gross Amount'),
    'val' => 1,
    ), array(
    'id' => 'NetAmount',
    'name' => $this->l('Net Amount'),
    'val' => 1,
    ), array(
    'id' => 'TaxRate',
    'name' => $this->l('Tax Rate'),
    'val' => 1,
    ), array(
    'id' => 'Currency',
    'name' => $this->l('Currency'),
    'val' => 1,                                    
    ),
    ),
    'id' => 'id',
    'name' => 'name'
    ),
    ),


    array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'name' => 'EXPORTORDERS_LOCATION',
    'label' => $this->l('Export Location'),
    'required' => true
    ),
    ),
    'submit' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('Save'),
    ),
    ),
    );

}

/**
* Set values for the inputs.
*/
protected function getConfigFormValues()
{
    return array(
    'EXPORTORDERS_LOCATION' => Configuration::get('EXPORTORDERS_LOCATION'),

    );
}


/**
* Save form data.
*/
protected function postProcess()
{
    //Initialise arrays and values
    $form_values = $this->getConfigFormValues();
    $_POST['module_name'] = 'export_orders';

    $arr = array_map('utf8_encode', $_POST);
    $test = json_encode($arr);       
    $insertData = array(
    'name'  => $_POST['module_name'], 
    'date_add'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 
    'value'  => $test

    );
    $updateData = array(   
    'date_upd'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),      
    'value'  => $test

    );

    //Fetch from configuration table
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'configuration WHERE name = "export_orders"';

    if ($row = Db::getInstance()->getRow($sql))
    $decoded_values = json_decode($row['value']);

    if($decoded_values == ""){

    Db::getInstance()->insert("configuration", $insertData);

}
else 

Db::getInstance()->update('configuration', $updateData, 'name = "export_orders"');
foreach (array_keys($form_values) as $key) {
// Configuration::updateValue($key, Tools::getValue($key));

}
}

/**
* Add the CSS & JavaScript files you want to be loaded in the BO.
*/
public function hookBackOfficeHeader()
{
    if (Tools::getValue('module_name') == $this->name) {
    $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'views/js/back.js');
    $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'views/js/back_checkall.js');
    $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'views/css/back.css');
}
}

/**
* Add the CSS & JavaScript files you want to be added on the FO.
*/
public function hookHeader()
{
    $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'/views/js/front.js');
    $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'/views/css/front.css');
}

public function hookDisplayBackOfficeHeader()
{
    /* Place your code here. */
}

public function hookDisplayBackOfficeHome()
{
    /* Place your code here. */
}
}
```

Also want to know how i can make select all to select all checkboxes. I have tried lot cant succeed, please help me

I had tried the checkbox to be checked but it is not getting right

Comment: I have absolutely no experience with Prestashop, but since this is just a PHP associative array: have you tried `'checked' => true` instead of `checked` (as that isn't a boolean value)?

Comment: #indextwo No it not works

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `$fields_value` array so that checkbox is checked by default.

```php
$helper = new HelperForm();
// set all form fields here...

$helper->fields_value[id_checkbox] = true;
```

Replace `id_checkbox` with ID of checkbox.

Make sure when the form is POST'ed with errors that you set the checkbox value as the user chose before form submission, otherwise the form will always have checkbox checked.

**EDIT:**

Ok, form helper creates checkbox names by using checkbox `nameProperty_checkboxId`. Since you don't have name property defined checkboxes will have name and id prefixed with `_`.

So remove the `$helper->fields_value[id_checkbox] = true;` line and modify your `getConfigValues()` method to this:

```php
/**
 * Set values for the inputs.
 */
protected function getConfigFormValues()
{
    return array(
        'EXPORTORDERS_LOCATION' => Configuration::get('EXPORTORDERS_LOCATION'),
        '_OrderID' => true
    );
}
```

Now your checkbox `Order ID` will be checked everytime the form is loaded. As said before, modify this to handle form submissions, saved settings etc.

Comment: @Tijojoel Then you are doing something wrong. Show us the entire code of form rendering, otherwise we can't help you further. Also tell us which version of prestashop you are using.

Comment: I had pasted  the complete code. Have a look at it.

Comment: prestshop 1.6 version

Comment: @Tijojoel I created a module from your code and for me it works.

Comment: #TheDrot Can you please share it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to generate group of checkboxes through PrestaShop helper:

Create an array for the number of checkboxes with labels.

```
$picking_history = array(
                               array(
                                   'check_id' => '1',
                                   'name' => $this->l('Customer Login Page'),
                               ),
                               array(
                                   'check_id' => '2',
                                   'name' => $this->l('Customer Registration Page'),
                               ),
                               array(
                                   'check_id' => '3',
                                   'name' => $this->l('Customer Contact Page'),
                               ),
                               array(
                                   'check_id' => '4',
                                   'name' => $this->l('Customer Forgotton Password Page'),
                               ),
                               array(
                                   'check_id' => '5',
                                   'name' => $this->l('Back Office Login Page'),
                               ),
                               array(
                                   'check_id' => '6',
                                   'name' => $this->l('Back Office Forgotton Password Page'),
                               ),
                           );
```

Add the following code to the helper form code to create a group of checkboxes.

```
array(
                       'type' => 'checkbox',
                       'label' => $this->l('Enable Google ReCaptcha for:'),
                       'hint' => $this->l('Please select the position of the Google Recaptcha.'),
                       'name' => 'google_recaptcha_check',
                       'values' => array(
                           'query' => $picking_history,
                           'id' => 'check_id',
                           'name' => 'name',
                           'desc' => $this->l('Please select atleast one position to enable plugin.'),
                       )
                   )
```

Comment: #Knowband then how it will be checked? and selected?

Answer (score 0):

In 1.6, for multiple checkboxes in adminController, let's say I have this in renderForm()

```
$this->fields_form['input'][] = [
                    'type' => 'checkbox',
                    'name' => 'buttons[]',
                    'label' => $this->l('Checkboxes'),
                    'class' => 'chosen',
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'required' => true,
                    'values' => array(
                        'query' => $buttons,
                        'id' => 'id_button',
                        'name' => 'name'
                    ),
];
```

According to this line in adminer/themes/default/template/helpers/form/form.tpl

```
<input type="checkbox" 
    name="{$id_checkbox}" 
    id="{$id_checkbox}" 
    ...
    {if isset($fields_value[$id_checkbox]) && $fields_value[$id_checkbox]} checked="checked"{/if} />
```

I'd have to send stored values from db via $checkboxes into Helper->fields_value, in my case like this:

```
     foreach ($checkboxes as $cb) {
        $this->fields_value['buttons[]_'.$cb] = true;
     }
```

my checkboxes are checked